# How to use struts tag in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, struts

I'm trying to get value from Action using Ajax request, but I'm having problem in using struts tag in javascript to show the value.

**Javascript code:**

```
 dojo.xhrPost({
            url: "dashboard"
            ,content: myParameterscomp
            , handle: function(response, ioargs) {

               if (ioargs.xhr.status == 200)
               {
                   var data = "<s:property value='#request.consumptionData'/>"
                   console.log(data);
               }

             }

            ,error: function (data) {
                handleError(data.description);
            }           
        });
```

**Java code:**

```
Map request = (Map)context.get("request");
 request.put("consumptionData",  43);
```

I'm getting the value of data as `<s:property value='#request.consumptionData'/>`  on console instead of **43**. I'm using struts2. My javascript code is in JSP file. Could anyone please tell me how can I show the value?

Comment: Just a question. did you include struts tag lib in your JSP file?

Comment: No. I've a loaded tag lib in my parent JSP and from there I'm calling above JSP to make AJAX request at the time of loading in parent JSP.

Comment: That wont work. You need to include taglib in the JSP where <s:property> tag is present.

Comment: Ok. Now, I'm getting empty value for the variable data. I also tried "<s:property value='%{#request.consumptionData}'/>" in javascript. But it also didn't work.

Comment: If you want to set value from request you can simply use ${consumptionData}

Comment: I want to know why I can't use struts2 tag in javascript, and what's wrong with above code.

Comment: Where your javascript code comes from? It must be in JSP in order to use Struts2 tags like you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to be calling /dashboard page via Ajax from your homepage. And expecting it to send you request attribute consumptionData. This won't work as your JSP does not contain required data. You need to put data in JSP and then fetch the same in Ajax. Convert your response to JSON. The simplest way of doing this would be to put following like of code in your Ajax response JSP.

Dashboard.jsp

```
{"consumptionData": < "<s:property value='#request.consumptionData'/>"}
```

And in main page when you load this JSP via ajax, you can parse this JSON output and use data in Javascript.

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);
var data = eval(json.consumptionData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code in browser accepts JSON. You could serialize you request as JSON and embed in you JavaScript file. For example:

```
var data = <%= toJson(request.get("consumptionData")) %>
```

If the data is simplely `Integer` values, you can even directly put the value in the code:

```
var data = <%= request.get("consumptionData") %>
```

The syntax could be vary (I'm not familiar with struts tag), but the idea is the same.